# How to show content if current_user meets the requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

How should I write a if condition in the view using Slim? I would like to show content if the current_user is a subscriber. I have a subscriptions table with a `user_id` and `cancelled` column. User has access to the website if their id can be found in the subscriptions table under `user_id` and the `cancelled` column is `NULL`. If `cancelled` has a `1` value then the user no longer has access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your relationship set up, something like this as an instance method in the user model should work.

```
def subscribed?
  subscriptions.where(cancelled: nil).exists?
end
```

Then in the view, you can do something like:

```
<% if user.subscribed? %>
  Here ya go
<% else %>
  Go away
<% end %>
```

You could obviously just put the logic in the subscribed? method in the view, but this is a little cleaner, maybe.